# load image in a modal before running a jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, plugins

I have been recently working on zooming in and zooming out of the images. The plugin I use [guillotine](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine), works perfectly apart from one little detail.

I am trying to get it working on the website that has been done in angularJS and displays a modal where the image resides. The specs of the plugin say that the image has to be loaded to get the plugin working properly. And this is my issue.

I have tried different jQuery/js events to make sure that the picture I am interested in is loaded before the plugin's function is fired. However, nothing seems to work.

Do you have any ideas how can I verify if the specific image that I am looking for in a modal window has been loaded properly before the jQuery with the plugin functions fires?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`load()` method is deprecated in jquery 1.8 .

You can load these `.js` files after all images in your page has loaded.

```js
jQuery(window).load(function(e) {
  //load plugin js file with ajax
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. I do use jQuery 1.8.2 unfortunately.

Comment: Just try using the method, it might work

Comment: I have tried and it did not work unfortunately.